# mantaining compatibility between CLion and eclipse in C project

Tags: c, eclipse, compilation, clion

i have a question that google couldn't solve. thing is i am currently working in a project with around 15 other people. some of us use eclipse and some use clion. the problem is that clion uses a "CMakeLists.txt" file in which specifies all files to be compiled. Eclipse doesn't use this file, but the ones using clion complain that they have to manually add all .c files created in eclipse in that file in order to compile the project. is there a way to get around this? thanks

Comment: I guess the issue if that eclipse can't update CMake project model (it actually creates eclipse project model out of it and continues working with the later), so since the eclipse project model is not supported in CLion (it works only with CMake), your colleagues have to manually update CMake project after someone changed the eclipse project. Not sure I can suggest a good solution here.

Comment: You could maintain CMakeLists.txt as your primary project model (check it into repo, etc.) and generate Eclipse CDT project files using CMake from that model. You could probably setup some hooks in Eclipse to ease keeping CDT project model files up to date.

Comment: how do i make that?